# Using RegistryKey, RegistrySecurity and RegistryAccessRule to repair bad registry settings on Windows XP

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I have a C# application that I am writing that will go repair broken registry keys across the organization.  I am trying to use the three classes of RegistryKey, RegistrySecurity and RegistryAccessRule and when I try to use them I get a "Requested registry access is not allowed.".  I have searched this extensively and cannot find a good solution.

The key's I am trying to fix, have no permissions on them (see screenshot below).  They are blank and have no inheritable settings.  This doesn't allow me to fix them with my app as I have no permissions, but I can change the permissions with the user I run this application as if I open regedit.  So I know I can add permissions to broken machines by manual means with this user, but for some reason my application no matter how hard I tell it to elevate itself cannot get the permissions.

Things I have tried:

1. On Windows 7 it works when you run the application with UAC, right click run as administrator. I would like to duplicate being able to do this on Windows XP with the same code.
2. I have created a manifest using level "highestAvailable" and also trying "requireAdministrator".
3. I have also tried using "System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission" assert which apparently will bring higher level of permissions to run as well.
4. I am not running this from a network share, although I have tried both local and network to see what security zone it would run from matters.

You can see what the permissions look like below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c99s.jpg

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try impersonating an administrator account from within your code, using P/Invoke to call the necessary api's like this person did to create an account impersonation class:

[Impersonator Class c#](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=10090)